# Сделать управляемый scroll Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Когда появляется новая запись в `textbox`, `scroll` сразу опускается вниз и если записи появляются довольно часто, не возможно нормально читать что было наверху.

Как это поправить ?

Comment: Что значит новая запись? Это же не ListBox

Comment: @Андрей когда появляется текст в TextBox, scroll улетает вниз если  читаю что то сверху.

Comment: т.е. текст у вас дописывается к существующему? А почему ListBox не использовать? Это логичнее, одно сообщение - один элемент.

Comment: @Андрей         public void Pisanina(string r)
 {textBox.AppendText(r + "\n");}

Comment: @Андрей Таким образом он появляется